# How can I return a larger dataframe from two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

e.g. I have two dataframes:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[6,5,4]})
b = pd.DataFrame({'A':[3,2,1],'B':[4,5,6]})
```

I want to get a dataframe `c` consisting of the larger value in each position of `a` & `b`:

```
c = max_function(a,b) = pd.DataFrame(max(a.iloc[i,j], b.iloc[i,j]))
c = pd.DataFrame({'A':[3,2,3],'B':[6,5,6]})
```

I don't want to generate `c` by comparing each value in `a` & `b` because the real dataframes in my work is very large.
So I wonder if there's a ready-made pandas function which can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [numpy.maximum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [6, 5, 4]})
b = pd.DataFrame({'A': [3, 2, 1], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
c = np.maximum(a, b)
print(c)
```

**Output**

```
   A  B
0  3  6
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Comment: That's what I need! Thanks!